# how to show a picture or text after scaling or rotating a button in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to show a picture or message after rotating or scaling a button in android.

```
btnRotate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        arg0.startAnimation(animRotate);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toasts to show messages:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

More info about toasts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 0):

To do anything after the animation ends. You can set an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener)) on animRotate and do whatever you need on its onAnimationEnd callback (which is called, as the name suggests, after the animation ends).

```
animRotate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
        // show a picture or message here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
    {

    }
});
```